# Access Image from Model

Tags: piranha-cms

I have an ImageRegion and can see the Image Guid file in my App_Data. What is the method for retrieving the image from within my Razor or Controller.

I have an embedded page model in my ViewModel;

```
public Piranha.Models.PageModel CMSData { get; set; }
```

and populate it in my controller

```
PhotoWeb.Models.LoginViewModel model = new Models.LoginViewModel();
model.CMSData = Piranha.Models.PageModel.GetByPermalink("welcome");
```

I can see the relevant ImageRegion using the expand object in my Razor

```
@Model.CMSData.Regions.Header
```

This gives me an ImageRegion containing the ID of the image file stored in App_Data\Content. Because App_Data is not accessible via a src tag for security reasons, what is the correct Piranha method for accessing the image and displaying it in my `<img>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need to prefix the Guid I get back from `@Model.CMSData.Regions.Header` with "media.ashx" as shown below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Replace the passed HTML content with one held in the CMS. If no match found
/// then the current content would be returned.
/// </summary>
public static string ReplaceImage(string current, 
    Func<Piranha.Extend.Regions.ImageRegion> cmsAccessor)
{
    Piranha.Extend.Regions.ImageRegion replacement = cmsAccessor();
    if (replacement == null)
    {
       return  current ;
    }
    return "media.ashx/" + replacement.Id.ToString();
}
```